# Unexpected '[' when using getimagesize()

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax, getimagesize

78I got some code, which used to work, but now passes an error:

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in (...)/utility_helper.php on line 47**

I have checked, over and over again, that all parenthesis and similar are closed, and I cant find anything which looks incorrect. The function including line 47 is this:

```
/*  image_ratio($img)
 *  Returns one (1) if the image is landscape ratio (width > height) or reutrns 
 *  zero (0) otherwise 
 */
function image_ratio($img) {
    $imgWidth  = getimagesize($img)[0]; // <-- Line 47
    $imgHeight = getimagesize($img)[1];

    if ($imgWidth/$imgHeight > 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

What the heck am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Changed link 47-48 to the following (old PHP version could not handle the above syntax):

```
$imgSize   = getimagesize($img);
$imgWidth  = $imgSize[0];
$imgHeight = $imgSize[1];
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? This syntax is supported only in PHP 5.4 and newer.

Comment: PHP < 5.4 doesn't support array dereferencing from a function return. Either update your PHP version or assign `getimagesize($img)` to a variable and reference the array from there.

Comment: try making $img an array first, so like $array = $img, then do getimagesize($array[0]);

Comment: God I need to find a new host for my site, thanks to all of you, once again an ancient version of PHP has caused me great pain. Ended up using the code in the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments by Ben, PHP < 5.4 doesn't support array dereferencing from a function. You should do it like this or update your PHP version:

```
function image_ratio($img) {
    $imgSize  = getimagesize($img); // <-- Line 47

    $imgWidth = $imgSize[0];
    $imgHeight = $imgSize[1];

    if (($imgWidth/$imgHeight) > 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, I was being too quick

Answer (score 2):

Make an array and then make the variables from the array like this:

```
$imageSize = getimagesize($img);
$imgWidth  = $imageSize[0];
$imgHeight = $imageSize[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP versions < 5.4 that do not support function array dereferencing you can instead use [list()](http://docs.php.net/list) to assign array elements to (single) variables.

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('...');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function image_ratio($img) {
    $imgSize = getimagesize($img);
    $imgWidth  = $imgSize[0];
    $imgHeight = $imgSize[1];

    if ($imgWidth/$imgHeight > 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```